# получить данные из файла в js после post

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть скрипт, для запроса

```
function add_but(pid_d, parent_d, total_cost_all){
        $.post("assets/get.php", { act:"add", aid:pid_d, acost:total_cost_all })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }
```

как мне в `js` получить несколько значений, а не целый `data`. Файл возвращает мне два параметра `cost` и `id`

Comment: Получить данные из запроса data,
обработать в функции .done, 
вернуть с помощью return.

Comment: а как их формировать в php? чтобы потом можно было распарсить?